# Lubuntu 19.04: How to add an app shortcut to taskbar?

Tags: lubuntu, lxqt

I right click on the app, but it just starts up. No way to add.
I don't understand terminal, so how to add shortcuts to taskbar?
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Right click on panel, go to *Configure Panel* and ensure you have "Quick Launch" widget enabled, then drag/drop menu items to the *Quick Launch* panel widget. Worry about the order of the dropped programs after adding them (you can move left-right then)

[image]

Even better, look up the documentation (*written by someone who's a better writer than me*)

**Updated Manual Links**

[Latest *stable* release (21.10 *currently*)](https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/5/5.1/lxqt-panel.html?highlight=quicklaunch)

[Latest *lts* release (20.04 *currently*)](https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/5/5.1/lxqt-panel.html?highlight=quicklaunch)

Comment: I have the quick launch widget in there. But it still wont work.
Any ideas?

Comment: I try to drag it onto the panel, but it wont let me - has he circle and red line through it so it is not being allowed.

Comment: You're possibly missing the *quicklaunch* widget, if positioned over where the *quicklaunch* widget, the red-X-circle changes to a blue-green-+ symbol, where I can 'let go' of left-mouse-button and the quick-launch expands with the added item.

Comment: I can drag it onto my desktop.  But the entire task bar is restricted. Cannot put it there

Comment: And it wont even launch from the desktop shortcut I made. Oh Linux,, why do you always have to be like this..

Comment: Are you using Lubuntu?    There is no Lubuntu 19 release (it's a desktop release, so is *yy.mm* in format).  The 'about lxqt' I dragged to desktop works as expected (I have to okay [click execute] the execution of the shortcut)

Comment: im using lubuntu 19 desktop. on my laptop

Comment: Since there is no Lubuntu 19 desktop, I'm guessing it's not Lubuntu at all.  Here is a link to Lubuntu's official site https://lubuntu.me/ or Ubuntu's official flavor selection screen (where you can select Lubuntu to see the choices) too https://www.ubuntu.com/download/flavours

Comment: https://lubuntu.me/disco-released/

Comment: *19.04 then thank you*. I booted a 19.04 box and it operates the same as my 19.10 machine. What application are you trying to move there? was it installed by default? or have you added it?  (if so how, is it a snap, compiled-from-source, from Ubuntu repo? ppa? or how - a link may provide clues if you don't understand these terms).

Comment: I figured it out, you have a TINY bit of taskbar that it will allow you to drop the shortcut onto. Easy to miss, Badly designed imo.
Thanks for your time

Comment: If readers need extra help; the following link may help - https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/using-the-taskbar-in-lubuntu-21-10/2816/4  (*the same details as written by Lyn in the manual; I try and describe to help another user*)

Answer (score 2):

Click the Start button - navigate to your icon - left click drag and drop it down on the quick launch area

You'll get a green circle with a plus in it.  It's not always easy dropping one on the ends, so just drop it anywhere to get it into the quick launch.

You can then right click and icon in the quick launch area and select Move Left or Move Right to position them

Answer (score 2):

In Lbuntu 20.04 with LXQt 0.14.1, it required me to drag the application from the Application window (bottom left corner) and drop over the PCMan-FM-Qt File manager (the only location where a green plus sign is shown).

If I tried to drop over the rest of the taskbar (the actual panel) or the widget area (right side corner icons, where the clock displays by default), the red circle with a line through it is displayed.

Comment: In 22.04, I found after much laziness and frustration that you must navigate to the application in the tree, you cannot drag a search result.

Answer (score 1):

On LUbuntu and Vbox 6.1
Right click anywhere in the desktop and -> Create Launcher.
Then fill in the name and then command (for example 'qterminal' to lauch terminal everytime you click the icon shortcut) and it is created a new icon on your Desktop!