# How to pin program on Taskbar in Lubuntu 20.04?

Tags: lubuntu, taskbar

how can I pin the program on Taskbar?

I use 20.04 Lubuntu as operating system.

Comment: @Someone where should i right click?

Comment: @Someone i tried it but i dont get "select create a launcher" option

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lubuntu 19.04: How to add an app shortcut to taskbar?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142290/lubuntu-19-04-how-to-add-an-app-shortcut-to-taskbar)

Comment: Thanks @Someone :)    Answer there updated with *modern* Lubuntu manual links too !  (*the answer was written pre-20.04 when only one manual was available; URLs changed now given more than one manual is published*; your *dup* to it allowed me to see & update it; so again thanks)